# YII2 sending email works on localhost but produce error on production server

Tags: email, yii2, smtp

Why is it that my application can send email when run on localhost but produce the following error on the production server. The same email is used and the same settings/codes is used.

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username
>   "myemail@sample.com" using 2 possible authenticators

Comment: have you turned the **Allow less secure apps** on?

Comment: no it was off. If i run the app on localhost it sends email successfully.

Comment: you need to allow less secure app **ON**

Comment: I mean yeah its on.